# Action doesn't dispatch data to reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo, redux-thunk

I'm trying to send a fetched data from my action to my save_user_reducer but it doesn't seem to work.

In my console log I can see that the ID was fetched, but the data isn't passed on with the dispatch command.

My auth actions:

```
    import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {Facebook} from 'expo';

import{
  FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAIL,
  TOKEN_RECEIVED,
  SAVE_USER
} from './types';


export const tryGetFacebookToken = () => async dispatch => {
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fb_token');
  let response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,picture`);
  const { id, picture, name } = await response.json();
  console.log("try facebook get", id);
  if (token) {
      dispatch({ type: TOKEN_RECEIVED, payload: token});
      dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {id:id});
      getUserInfo(token, dispatch);
      console.log('got a token');
  }
}



async function getUserInfo(token, dispatch) {

  let response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,picture`);
  const { id, picture, name } = await response.json();
  //console.log('picture' + JSON.stringify(await response.json().picture))
  console.log('the response is id: ' + id + " name " + name);
  return dispatch({ type: SAVE_USER, payload: {id: id} })
}
```

and save_user_reducer:

```
import {SAVE_USER} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE ={
    id: '',
    name: ''
  }; //empty initial state

export default (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) =>{
  console.log("save reducer called" + action.payload);
  switch(action.type){
    case SAVE_USER:
        return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value};
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-ordered how the dispatch is passed to the second function to getInfo(dispatch, token)  and it works!